# Show that a graph $G$ is a forest if and only if every induced subgraph of $G$ contains a vertex of degree at most $1$

Tags: graph-theory

I'm new with this, so I'd like to know if someone can help me to solve this problem, I really don't know how to solve it, thanks!

Show that a graph $G$ is a forest if and only if every induced subgraph of $G$ contains a vertex of degree at most $1$

Comment: What's your definition for forest? ​ Do you have any other characterizations of being a forest? ​ Do you have any ideas for either direction of the if-and-ony-if? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: It may be easier to think about the contrapositive: Show that $G$ is a _non-forest_ if and only if it has an induced subgraph where every vertex has degree $\ge 2$.